# Osmdroid not working well on Android 6.0

Tags: android, osmdroid

I created an Android app with Osmdroid 4.2. Everything works fine, but in the last two weeks I see problems on Nexus devices with Android 6.0: the OSM map is not loading, you see only a grey background on the map. The maptiles arenot showing on Android 6.0.

Comment: We feel very sorry for you. But why tell this on this site? You should report such things to osmdroid directly.

Comment: I bet its a permissions thing

Answer (score 4):

The osmdroid sample app was recently updated for android m support.  Basically you have to ask the user for explicit permissions for network and storage access.

This guides you through the basics
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

This the related OSMdroid ticket
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/178

This is the related code to copy and paste into your start up activity. Note, requires 23 build tools

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.osmdroid.MapActivity;

public class SampleLoader extends ListActivity {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    final int INTERNET=1;
    final int NETSTATE=2;
    final int LOCATION=3;
    final int LOCATIONC=4;
    final int WIFI=5;
    final int STORAGE=6;
    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Assume thisActivity is the current activity
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Need internet access to get map tiles if working with online sources", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                        INTERNET);
            }
        }

        permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);

        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Need to check network state", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE},
                        NETSTATE);

            }
        }

        permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Need your location to place an icon on the map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        LOCATION);

            }
        }

        permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Need your location to place an icon on the map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        LOCATIONC);

            }
        }

        permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Access WIFI state", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE},
                        WIFI);

            }
        }

        permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "We store tiles to your devices storage to reduce data usage and for reading offline tile stores", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        STORAGE);

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case INTERNET:{
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay!
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Online map sources will be unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            case NETSTATE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay!
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Online map sources will be unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            case LOCATION:{
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay!
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this,"My location will be unavailable via GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            case LOCATIONC:
            {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay!
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this,"My location will be unavailable via Network providers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            case STORAGE:{
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay!
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Offline map data and caching will be unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            case WIFI:{
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay!


                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Data usage may not be optimized.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking for Internet and Network state permissions? They are both "Normal" permissions and they are granted by default at the app installation point. You can check out the normal permissions here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html